# I get a weird margin-right when using bootstrap's grid system. I overwrote the .container, .row, and .col-lg-6 margin and padding properties to be 0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to divide my page into two columns stretching all the way from the left edge of the screen to the right. I am using twitter bootstrap's grid structure, and this is the code I have -

```
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-6>
                <img src='image.jpg' width='200px'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-lg-6>
                <img src='image.jpg' width='200px'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want no margin and padding so I have overwritten the .container, .row, and .col-lg-6 class' margin and padding properties to 0px.

But I still get a weird gap between the two columns and the right edge of the screen. What could be causing this?

[The right gap after the second image. The columns have a red border to make them easier to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmMMZ.png)

Comment: Which bootstrap ? Where is the code you changed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width to parent element as well. Right now your `.container` is 400px because it takes the width of your pictures. If you define a specific width in `.container` you would notice the difference.

Comment: I figured it out. Using .container-fluid instead of .container fixed it. I looked at the bootstrap 4 docs where it said that .container takes a width of 1140px instead of 100% on large screens. .container-fluid takes 100% of the screen width